# How can one solve $\left|\frac{x\cdot \:e^{-nx^2}}{n}\right|\le\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to prove that the following function series converges to a continuous $f$ in the real domain.
 $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{x\cdot e^{-nx^2}}{n}$$
So, the path that I've chosen is proving that the limit function $f$ exists by using the Weierstrass M-test. Then to demonstrate that the $f$ is continuous I'd have to prove that the sequence of functions is also continuous. The second part is quite easy. Using Weierstrass M-test is kind of challenging, at least to me, especially when trying to find a sequence that bounds the sequence of functions, such that
$\left|f_n\left(x\right)\right|\le a_n$ , $\forall \:x\in \:\mathbb{R}$  and also  $\forall \:n\in \mathbb{N}\ge \:1$.

So the process would go like this...

$$\left|\frac{x\cdot \:e^{-nx^2}}{n}\right|=\frac{\left|x\right|\cdot e^{-nx^2}}{n}\le a_n$$

Now, I'm trying to get rid off the x. So, being $\:e^{-nx^2}\le 1$ I could just write down:

$$\frac{\left|x\right|\cdot \:\:e^{-nx^2}}{n}\le \frac{\left|x\right|}{n}\le a_n$$

I don't believe I can further keep up the chain of inequalities from there, and even if I did, it would be useless as the series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{n}$ diverges. I tried using other boundaries but I couldn't make it work.

So after a while, I decided to just jump to sequences that I know their series converge. And with a little bit of graphing and Wolfram Mathematica, I came up with:
 $$\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

So by using this sequence, I could prove that the series converges to an $f$ because:

1. $$\left|\frac{x\cdot \:e^{-nx^2}}{n}\right|\le\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
2. $$\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}} \ge 0$$
3. $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}},converges$$

The problem would be solved very quickly without question. But then I would've learned nothing.

How can I prove $\left|\frac{x\cdot \:e^{-nx^2}}{n}\right|\le\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ ?

And also, coming up with $\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ was simple because I had tools that allowed me to do it easily. So, knowing that $\frac{1}{n^p}$ is widely used to study the convergence and divergence of series, improper integrals, etc. The very question I should ask myself is for what values of $p$ is $\left|\frac{x\cdot \:e^{-nx^2}}{n}\right|\le\frac{1}{n^p}$. ($p$ being in this case greater than one)

$p=\frac{3}{2}$ is one of them. But there are many numbers out there and coming up with the right one, you could say is pretty difficult.

So, in synthesis, what I'm asking for is how can one solve:

$$\left|\frac{x\cdot \:e^{-nx^2}}{n}\right|\le\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
$$(\left|x\right|\cdot e^{-nx^2}\le n^{-\frac{1}{2}})$$

And

$$\left|\frac{x\cdot \:e^{-nx^2}}{n}\right|\le\frac{1}{n^p}$$
$$(\left|x\right|\cdot \:\:\:e^{-nx^2}\le n^{-p+1})$$

Note: I somewhat struggle to do two variables inequalities, so my abilities and knowledge in respect to three variable inequalities are very little, if not null. So I don't know if I'm asking for something that's out of this world with my second inquiry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write
$$
\frac{x e^{-nx^2}}{n} = \frac{\sqrt{n}\,x\, e^{-nx^2}}{n^{3/2}} = \frac{f(\sqrt{n}\,x)}{n^{3/2}}
$$
with $f(y) = \sqrt{y}\, e^{-y}$. Since $f$ is bounded for $y≥0$, your bound follows.

More precisely, if you want to know the maximum of $f$, remark that $f(0) = 0$ and $f\underset{\infty}\to 0$ and $f≥0$, therefore, its maximum is reached in some point $y_0\in(0,\infty)$ and
$$
f'(y_0) = e^{-y_0}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y_0}} - \sqrt{y_0}\right) = 0.
$$
We deduce that $y_0 = 1/2$, and so $f(y)≤ f(1/2) = e^{-1/2}/\sqrt{2} ≤ 1$. Thus
$$
\left|\frac{x e^{-nx^2}}{n}\right| \leq \frac{e^{-1/2}}{\sqrt{2}\,n^{3/2}} \leq \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}
$$